# How do I build with the old version of Xcode on Mountain Lion?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, osx-mountain-lion, xcode3to4

I just upgraded from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion, and I'm trying to get a project to build using an older version of Xcode, 3.2.6. I ran `sudo xcode-select --switch /Developer` but now when I try to build my project with `xcodebuild`, I get

```
xcrun: Error: failed to exec real xcrun. (No such file or directory)
```

It builds just fine from within the IDE. How can I get this to build from the CLI again?

Comment: Which "old version" ? I still use Xcode 3.2.6 alongside Xcode 4.5.2 on Mountain Lion, so it's definitely possible for at least some older versions.

Comment: Thanks, I should've mentioned that. I meant 3.2.6.

Comment: OK - I don't use xcodebuild but builds from within Xcode itself seem to work fine, as does debugging etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I had to specify the full path `/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild` in my build script.